# Как правильно обрезать низ изображения?

Tags: html, css, svg

Имеется 2 блока, у каждого из блоков задан `bg` изображением. Как правильно `bg` первого блока с низу обрезать так, чтобы получилось примерно то, что имеется на скрине?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/
http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Полностью адаптивно к любому размеру экрана. Работает во всех браузерах.

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:grey;
background-position: 0% 50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container" >
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0,1 0,0.5  0.5,0.67 1,0.5 1,1"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/400/300/any" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не лучший вариант конечно. [Ссылка](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.item:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(51% 100%, 100% 60%, 100% 0, 0 0, 0 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(51% 100%, 100% 60%, 100% 0, 0 0, 0 60%);
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.item:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/300);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Картинка не масштабируется

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, исправил, вопрос заключался в том, как сделать углы, поэтому не предусмотрел этого:)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, благодарю